# Repeat function with general command (without mentioning function name)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, function, repeat

How do I repeat a swift function without naming that functions name?

Like if I have this function:

```
func repeatAtFail(){
  let hasFailed = Bool.random()
  if(hasFailed){
    //repeat this function without calling function name
  }
  print("function succeed")
}
```

So I am looking for a general command to repeat a function. Just like "Return". But Return exits the function and I need one command that repeats it.

---

EDIT 11:08

This is the function I have

```
func loadRun(){
    let request = get_request(postString: "function_name=get_run&userid=\(userid)&token=\(token!)")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            guard let data = data else {
                self.showErrorMessage()
                //HERE I NEED TO REPEAT THE FUNCTION
                throw JSONError.NoData
            }
            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary else {
                self.showErrorMessage()
                throw JSONError.ConversionFailed
            }
            if(checkErrors(json: json)){
                self.showErrorMessage(message:json["error"] as! String)
                return
            }

            self.data = json["payload"] as! [[String: Any]]
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                self.loadingBar.stopAnimating()
            }
        } catch let error as JSONError {
            self.showErrorMessage()
            print(error.rawValue)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            self.showErrorMessage()
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

Occasionally it occurs that I get error -999 which is probably due to a failure of the SSL certificate on the domain. Till that issue is fixed I need a solution to reload the function so the users don't face any issues.

Comment: Are you looking for the `while` (or `repeat`) statement?

Comment: There's no such thing, use a loop. What are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: use do while ..

Comment: @MartinR Please check updated post

Comment: @mag_zbc Please check updated post

Comment: If the server's SSL certificate is invalid then repeating the request probably won't help...

Comment: @MartinR it helps. I am getting the -999 error occasionally, like 1 out of 10 times.

Comment: @sdd, `-999` error is `NSURLErrorCancelled` — it's not SSL certificate error, and just signs that request was cancelled before it could finish. You should check your app's logic instead of trying to build some scheme to circumvent this problem.

Comment: Why don’t you just call the function ‘loadRun()’